# ionic cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi guys i am using **`node server`** for data fetch and and client side is my `ionic framework` for android application(phonegap).

so in my computer browser i hit `localhost:8080/sessions` (or `10.129.86.47:8080/sessions`) then it will return `json` from server side,but when I run this ionic application in android device as an `apk` then it will not hit to server because of *cross domain.*

My server and my client application both are in same network.

I fond 2 to 3 solution but it will not work for me

Solution which I tried are as:

1) first I tried **`ionic proxy`**, I set proxy for ionic which will hit my proxy url but it wont work.
example : in ionic.project file I entered proxy

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/sessions",
      "proxyUrl": "http://10.129.86.47:8080/sessions"
    }
  ]
}
```

2) second i tried Whitelist 
example :

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />
<access origin="https://google.com" />
<access origin="*" />    <!-- Don't block any requests -->
```

if i use **`*`** then it means Don't block any requests  but it wont work for me

As i know when phonegap android application hit service it will hit url like 
file://and ....... so it will not hit my server form application but **Cordova** allows cross domain request by default but for me it wont work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Headers,  Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on the server?

Comment: yes i done that part also

Comment: Is your application connecting to the network? What is the exact error shown in console log?

Comment: yes i am connected to same network and if i hit same url from my android browser then server respond with json but if  same url i am hiting from android app then it wont work bcz at that time my url is not http it will become file://................. and i see my log remotely on computer browser and also in android logcat actually it is not hiting url bcz of file://  i think

Comment: if you have cordova 5.0.0, then you need https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for CORS

Comment: try the solution @aorfevre and try to put <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http:"> in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually only running ionic serve.

You can avoid to modify your project and use an extension to disable CORS, for chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related

For firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/